# compare columns in a one file and print the count of matches

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a CSV file that contains two columns. I want to compare the two columns and print the number of matches.

`file1`

```
M,M
A,M
A,A
M,A
```

Expected output:

If the first columns in the first row is the same, I want to print the second column in the output file, i.e.

```
M (for first line)
0 (for second line not same, zero value)
A (for third line)
0 (for fourth line not same, zero value)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F , '{ if ($1 == $2) print $2; else print 0; }' inputfile
```

Comment: this code is not working properly.

Comment: the columns are seperated by comma. the input file is a csv file

Comment: @RincyRaphael I see your new question edit. If you don't ask the right question you won't get the right answer. I will ask again - are there blank lines in your input like you have in your question?

Comment: no there is no black lines...

Comment: the code is working, but i need to print the column two values also

Comment: @RincyRaphael I am only answering what you have in your question. If you want something put it in your question. Your question says "Expected output: `2`" so that is what I gave you. If you want something else ask for it. I can not read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU grep`:

```
$ grep -cP '(.+) \1' file
2
```

With your updated input:

```
$ grep -cP '(.+),\1' file    
2
```

**Updated**

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F',' '{print $1 == $2 ? $2 : 0}' file
M
0
A
0
```

If you can use `perl`:

```
$ perl -F',' -anle 'print $F[0] eq $F[1] ? $F[1] : 0' file
M
0
A
0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '!/^$/ && $1 == $2 { numMatch++ }; END { print numMatch }' YourFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `awk` command,

```
awk -F, '!/^$/ {if($1==$2) {print $2} else {print "0"}}' file
```